# django templatetags template , combine {{ }} method call with template tag context variable

Tags: python, django

i m trying to make the result of a template tag dependent from another template tag. the use case is the following. i have a headers list which contains all the columns i want to show in a table + the column of the model they are showing  +whether they are visible or not.

```
LIST_HEADERS = (
    ('Title', 'title', True),
    ('First Name', 'first_name', True),
    ('Last Name', 'last_name', True),
    ('Modified At', 'modified', False),
)
```

now i have a templatetag which prints out all the headers. consequently i wanted to create a template tag which prints out the body of the table. therefore i want to take the headers list and check which header is visible and want to accordingly show or hide my  value.

therefore i created the templatetag template below:

```
<tr class="{% cycle odd,even %}">
  {% for header in headers %}
  {% if header.visible %}
    <td><a href="{{ model_instance.get_absolute_url|escape }}">{{ model_instance.title }}</a></td>
  {% else %}
    <td style="visibility:hidden;"><a href="{{ model_instance.get_absolute_url|escape }}">{{ model_instance.title }}</a></td>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</tr>
```

you see the value {{ model_instance.title }} there. this value i want to change to model_instance.title, model_instance.first_name, model_instance.last_name, ... at runtime.

thus i m searching a way how i can combine {{ model_instance }} with header.model_column .

model_column equals to the second entry in the LIST_HEADERS. Thus model_column would be title, first_name,..

thus the solution would be something like [pseudocode] {{ model_instance.header.model_column  }} [pseudocode]

..thus i search a way how i can combine a django template method call with a django template tag attribute..huh.. sounds crazy :D

i hope i explained it good enough! probably there is a much easier solution to my problem. but this seems to me pretty generic and easy and would work.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this as a filter, as they provide an easy way to render a result dependent on the value of a variable.

```
@register.filter
def field_from_name(instance, field_name):
    return getattr(instance, field_name, None)
```

and then in the template:

```
{{ model_instance|field_from_name:header.model_column }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplify this.

First, read about the things the Django template language actually *can* do.   It's not much.  It can deference variables, lists and dictionaries.

It's simpler if you do all the "work" in your view function.

```
show = [ ]
for  title, field_name, visible in LIST_HEADERS:
     if visible: style= "visibility:hidden"
     else: style= ""
     show.append( (style, title, getattr(object,field_name) )
render_to_response( "template", { 'show_list': show, ... }, ... )
```

In your template

```
{% for style, name, value in show_list %}
<tr class="{% cycle odd,even %}">
    <td class="{{style}}"><a href="...">{{value}}</a></td>
{% endfor %}
```

Indeed, I'd suggest dropping LIST_HEADERS from your view function.

```
show = [ 
    ("", 'Title', object.title),
    ("",'First Name', object.first_name),
    ("",'Last Name', object.last_name),
    ("visibility:hidden",'Modified At', object.modified),
]
render_to_response( "template", { 'show_list': show, ... }, ... )
```

I find the above much easier to work with because it's explicit and it's in the view function.

Comment: +1 for doing more in the view, less in the template. It will make everything more readable.

Comment: wow.. impressing. so fast.. and i learned a lot from your post.