# comparing custom template tag within if tag

Tags: django-templates

i have a custom template tag that takes some argument and calculates the result.
I want to compare that value obtained from that custom tag with another variable.

Custom template tag(having three arguments)

{% price_for_pax service pax '' %}

variable :

{{service.price}}

What i want is

```
{% if service.price == price_for_pax service pax '' %}
    do something
{% endif %}
```

When i look for the result it does not show anything
Can i compare like this ? If not what can be the solution ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There were a couple of questions similar to this before:

[Django - use template tag and 'with'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697757/django-use-template-tag-and-with)

[django templatetags template , combine {{ }} method call with template tag context variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958286/django-templatetags-template-combine-method-call-with-template-tag-conte)

Making a template filter rather than a template tag could do the trick.

Comment: HI aruseni i am doing this but still facing problem {% with service pax ''|price_for_pax as pp %} service,pax ,'' are the parameters and price_for_pax is a function in template filter. I convert into template filter